# Javascript function factory nested in an immediate function nested inside a jQuery ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, factory

In this pattern there is an immediate function wrapped inside a jQuery ready.

```
    $((function(_this) {
      return function() {
        document.write('called!');
      };
    })(this));
```

I don't understand to what the returned function is assigned to and how it is called.

http://codepen.io/florian/pen/OyLoRd

From my understanding of function factory, you need to assign them to a variable, but here I don't get where the return is going to be assigned to.

Is there something special in the jQuery.ready() function that I am not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: It's an [immediate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) function.

Comment: I know about the wrapper pattern although I didn't know it was called immediate function (I am going to update that to be clearer). But my concerned is about how the returned function is assigned and then called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed up an immediate function with the jQuery ready event callback.

Generally, when you want to execute code on document ready, you do it like this

```
$(function() {
  // code
});
```

The final result of your code is similar to that of the following code:

```
$(function() {
    document.write('called!');
});
```

And here is a breakdown:

```
var func = function(_this) {
    return function() {
        document.write('called!');
    };
};

var onReady = func(this); // In your code, the declation of func and its exection are done together

// At this point onReady is equal to the inner function
// function() {
//    document.write('called!');
// }

$(onReady);
```

Comment: oh ok I see. I was aware of the ready function wrapping the immediate function but I was totally confused by this func var. That makes a lot more sense now.